# How to Get Response Body as Array Buffer using HTTPS module in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, arraybuffer

I am trying to fetch an image using the native node.js `https` module and receive the response body as an array buffer.

With axios, you can simply do this:

```js
axios.get('https://placehold.co/600x400', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
```

But I haven't been able to figure out how to get the body as an array buffer using the `https` module.

So far I have been able to only get the response data as raw, not as an array buffer.

```js
const https = require('https');

const request = https.request('https://placehold.co/600x400', (response) => {
    let data = ''

    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data = data + chunk.toString()
    })
  
    response.on('end', () => {
        console.log(data)
    })
})
  
request.end()
```

I have tried doing `Buffer.from(data, 'utf-8')` but it doesn't work. I also tried doing `new TextEncoder().encode(data)` but it didn't work either.

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `chunk` value is already a Buffer.  So, if you just accumulate all the chunks you get as buffers, you will end up with a single buffer that contains all your data.  You can then do whatever you need to with the data (use it as is, decode it, convert to a string, etc...).

```js
const https = require('https');

const request = https.request('https://placehold.co/600x400', (response) => {
    let buffer;

    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        if (!buffer) {
            buffer = chunk;
        } else {
            buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, chunk]);
        }
    });

    response.on('end', () => {
        console.log(buffer);
    });
})

request.end();
```